# Find and replace button works but takes me to a new page

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in JavaScript and I've been working on this project which uses regular expressions to find and replace particular strings on a text.

I'd say it's working pretty well, but when I click the 'go' button in order to replace the string, it does so, but takes me to a new page which only contains the replaced string. The console says something about "Quirks mode"? not sure what that is.

Here's my code:

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>findNreplace</title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="input" id="inputText">
    </textarea>
    <p id="projectedText"></p>
    <label for="find">Find: </label>
    <input type="text" id="find">
    <label for="replace">Replace: </label>
    <input type="text" name="" id="replace">
    <input type="button" value="Go" id="commit">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

```
document.getElementById("commit").onclick=findNreplace; //set up go button


//variables
var textToShow = document.getElementById("inputText");
var projected = document.getElementById("projectedText");
var toFind = document.getElementById("find");
var toReplace = document.getElementById("replace"); 

// set up text area to project the input into the paragraph
textToShow.addEventListener('input',updateValue);

function updateValue(text) {
    projected.textContent=text.target.value;
}

// replace function
function findNreplace() {
    var str = projected.innerText;
    var regex = new RegExp(toFind.value, 'g')
    var found = projected.innerText.match(regex);
    document.write(str.replace(regex.source, toReplace.value))
    console.log(regex.source);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**;TLDR**

Do not use `document.write` outside of a tutorial exercise to insert content into the HTML input stream during page load.

---

## `document.write`, `.open` and `.close`

During page load, when the HTML parser is processing the  HTML input stream, the document is open, and you can use `document.write` to insert content into the input stream at its current position.

When the page has finished loading from its input stream, the document is automatically closed.

If you call `document.write` on a closed document it will automatically open the document for you. This *opening the document again* resets the document to an empty state - of having no content. This is why you only see what you have written.

If the document is opened by `document.write` it will stay open until you explicitly call `document.close`. This is why if the browser displays a page loading indicator, it will remain active until `document.close` is called.

In most cases `document.write` is used in beginners' JavaScript programming course so they see results of example tasks quickly. It has a place in inserting HTML input during page load but has its limitations<sup>1</sup>.

**Notes**

<sup>1</sup>`document.write` can be used during page load to dynamically insert script tags that need to be loaded synchronously. Browsers sometimes [ignore such insertions](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/removing-document-write/), but inserting  scripts from the same domain as the HTML page is allowed.

See also [Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/5217142)

### Quirks mode

The quirks mode warning is being issued because the HTML document does not start with a document type declaration.  Insert the following line,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

as the first line of HTML source to have the page parsed according to standards.

---

### Appending HTML to a document.

[Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) invokes the HTML parser on a markup string and allows you to append HTML to a specified element.

Here's an example of using it to append HTML to a page, after `document.body` has been created, without using `document.write`:

```js
// bodyAppend - append HTML string to body

function bodyAppend( htmlString) {
   document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlString);
}

// and test

bodyAppend("<p style='color:green'>An appended paragraph</p>");
```

```html
<h1>Page Header</h1>

Some existing page content.
```

- 'insertAdjacentHTML' can't be used in the head section of a page - `document.body` has not been created and is still set to `null`,
- `bodyAppend` presented above is intended for beginners - it's just one example of a particular technique. Please read the linked documentation to understand the syntax used, and  do a search for "how to modify the DOM in JavaScript" to learn more about the scope of the topic.

Comment: But I'm not sure what to use in order to get the results I want